# Is there any way to become a member of group with known id using javascript API

Tags: soundcloud

Is there any way to become a member of group with known id using javascript API.
I can't find this ability both here https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/users and here https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/groups

Other question  - Am I right that it is necessity to be member of group to contribute my track with API

thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately we don't expose the join group functionality at the moment. 
But you can still contribute to a group without being a member using:

```
SC.put("/groups/{id}/contributions/{track_id}", function(){
  console.log("contributed");
});
```